# C# XML Serializer Nested Elements Access Objects

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, schema, xml-serialization

I have an XSD generated by the XSD.exe tool. I am loading data from an Excel sheet and filling a data table, then I want to save that data to an XML file. How do I serialize the nested elements?

in my schema: (under Providers there can be multiple Provider and under ProviderSites there can be multiple ProviderSite)

```
<xs:element name="Providers">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Provider">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FederalTaxIdentifier" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProviderName" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ContractualRelationshipCode" type="xs:string" />
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProviderSites">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ProviderSite">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SiteIdentifier" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SiteName" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LicenseTypeCode" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OpenDate" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CloseDate" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DirectorPrefixName" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DirectorFirstName" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DirectorMiddleInitial" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DirectorLastName" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DirectorPhoneNumber" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NationalProviderIdentifier" type="xs:string" />
                      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="WebAddress" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:all>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs: element>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:all>   
    </xs:element>       
  </xs:sequence>
```

in my c# I created a new instance of the element Providers->Provider

```
ProvidersProvider prov = new ProvidersProvider();
```

and I access an object and set it to the cell in my data table

```
prov.FederalTaxIdentifier = DtRow.ItemArray[0].ToString();
```

then serialize it to the xml

```
serializer.Serialize(writer, prov);
```

Trying to figure out how to access and add the other elements like Providers->Provider->ProviderSites->ProviderSite->SiteIdentifier

**UPDATE**
I added a xs:choice element to the xsd and re-generated the class. 
How do I go about setting those elements?

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProviderSitePhones">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ProviderSitePhone">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                       <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="TypeCode" type="xs:string" />
                           <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PhoneNumber" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:choice>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="action" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
       </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In the XSD class:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
public partial class ProvidersProviderProviderSiteProviderSitePhone {

    private string[] itemsField;

    private ItemsChoiceType[] itemsElementNameField;

    private string actionField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("PhoneNumber", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TypeCode", typeof(string))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public string[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName {
        get {
            return this.itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string action {
        get {
            return this.actionField;
        }
        set {
            this.actionField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(IncludeInSchema=false)]
public enum ItemsChoiceType {

    /// <remarks/>
    PhoneNumber,

    /// <remarks/>
    TypeCode,
}
```

In my Program.cs I have:

```
ProviderSitePhones = provider.Value.Select(ProviderSitePhone => new ProvidersProviderProviderSiteProviderSitePhone()
{

}).ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try code like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("FederalTaxIdentifier", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProviderName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ContractualRelationshipCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SiteIdentifier", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SiteName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("LicenseTypeCode", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("OpenDate", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("CloseDate", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DirectorPrefixName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DirectorFirstName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DirectorMiddleInitial", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DirectorLastName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DirectorPhoneNumber", typeof(string));


            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "123", "alpha", "100", "1000", "abc", "code1","1/1/2000", "2/1/2000", "Mr.", "John", "L", "Smith", "800-555-1234"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "123", "alpha", "100", "1001", "abc", "code1", "1/1/2000", "2/1/2000", "Mrs.", "Mary", "L", "Smith", "800-555-1234" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "123", "alpha", "100", "1001", "abc", "code1", "1/1/2000", "2/1/2000", "Mr.", "Harry", "L", "Smith", "800-555-1234" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "456", "beta", "100", "2000", "abc", "code1", "1/1/2000", "2/1/2000", "Mr.", "John", "L", "Smith", "800-555-1234" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "456", "beta", "100", "2001", "abc", "code1", "1/1/2001", "2/1/2001", "Mr.", "Ralph", "L", "Smith", "800-555-1234" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "456", "beta", "100", "2002", "abc", "code1", "1/1/2000", "2/1/2000", "Mr.", "Brutus", "L", "Smith", "800-555-1234" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "789", "gama", "100", "3000", "abc", "code1", "1/1/2000", "2/1/2000", "Mrs.", "Ronda", "L", "Smith", "800-555-1234" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "789", "gama", "100", "3001", "abc", "code1", "2/1/2000", "3/1/2000", "Mr.", "George", "L", "Smith", "800-555-1234" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "789", "gama", "100", "3002", "abc", "code1", "3/1/2000", "4/1/2000", "Mrs.", "Linda", "L", "Smith", "800-555-1234" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "789", "gama", "100", "3003", "abc", "code1", "4/1/2000", "5/1/2000", "Mrs.", "Sally", "L", "Smith", "800-555-1234" });

            var dict = 
                dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("FederalTaxIdentifier"), y => y)
                          .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y
                              .GroupBy(a => a.Field<string>("SiteIdentifier"), b => b)
                              .ToDictionary( a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()));




            Providers providers = new Providers();

            providers.Provider = dict.Select(provider => new ProvidersProvider()
            {
                FederalTaxIdentifier = provider.Key,
                ProviderName = provider.Value.FirstOrDefault().Value.Field<string>("ProviderName"),
                ContractualRelationshipCode = provider.Value.FirstOrDefault().Value.Field<string>("ContractualRelationshipCode"),
                ProviderSites = provider.Value.Select(site => new ProvidersProviderProviderSite()
                {
                    SiteIdentifier = site.Key,
                    SiteName = site.Value.Field<string>("SiteName"),
                    LicenseTypeCode = site.Value.Field<string>("LicenseTypeCode"),
                    OpenDate = site.Value.Field<string>("OpenDate"),
                    CloseDate = site.Value.Field<string>("CloseDate"),
                    DirectorPrefixName = site.Value.Field<string>("DirectorPrefixName"),
                    DirectorFirstName = site.Value.Field<string>("DirectorFirstName"),
                    DirectorMiddleInitial = site.Value.Field<string>("DirectorMiddleInitial"),
                    DirectorLastName = site.Value.Field<string>("DirectorLastName"),
                    DirectorPhoneNumber = site.Value.Field<string>("DirectorPhoneNumber")
                }).ToArray()
            }).ToArray();

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Providers));
            serializer.Serialize(writer,providers);


        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // <auto-generated>
    //     This code was generated by a tool.
    //     Runtime Version:2.0.50727.6421
    //
    //     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
    //     the code is regenerated.
    // </auto-generated>
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // 
    // This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=2.0.50727.3038.
    // 


    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class Providers {

        private ProvidersProvider[] providerField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Provider", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public ProvidersProvider[] Provider {
            get {
                return this.providerField;
            }
            set {
                this.providerField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
    public partial class ProvidersProvider {

        private string federalTaxIdentifierField;

        private string providerNameField;

        private string contractualRelationshipCodeField;

        private ProvidersProviderProviderSite[] providerSitesField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string FederalTaxIdentifier {
            get {
                return this.federalTaxIdentifierField;
            }
            set {
                this.federalTaxIdentifierField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string ProviderName {
            get {
                return this.providerNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.providerNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string ContractualRelationshipCode {
            get {
                return this.contractualRelationshipCodeField;
            }
            set {
                this.contractualRelationshipCodeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("ProviderSite", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, IsNullable=false)]
        public ProvidersProviderProviderSite[] ProviderSites {
            get {
                return this.providerSitesField;
            }
            set {
                this.providerSitesField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
    public partial class ProvidersProviderProviderSite {

        private string siteIdentifierField;

        private string siteNameField;

        private string licenseTypeCodeField;

        private string openDateField;

        private string closeDateField;

        private string directorPrefixNameField;

        private string directorFirstNameField;

        private string directorMiddleInitialField;

        private string directorLastNameField;

        private string directorPhoneNumberField;

        private string nationalProviderIdentifierField;

        private string webAddressField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string SiteIdentifier {
            get {
                return this.siteIdentifierField;
            }
            set {
                this.siteIdentifierField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string SiteName {
            get {
                return this.siteNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.siteNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string LicenseTypeCode {
            get {
                return this.licenseTypeCodeField;
            }
            set {
                this.licenseTypeCodeField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string OpenDate {
            get {
                return this.openDateField;
            }
            set {
                this.openDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string CloseDate {
            get {
                return this.closeDateField;
            }
            set {
                this.closeDateField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string DirectorPrefixName {
            get {
                return this.directorPrefixNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.directorPrefixNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string DirectorFirstName {
            get {
                return this.directorFirstNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.directorFirstNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string DirectorMiddleInitial {
            get {
                return this.directorMiddleInitialField;
            }
            set {
                this.directorMiddleInitialField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string DirectorLastName {
            get {
                return this.directorLastNameField;
            }
            set {
                this.directorLastNameField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string DirectorPhoneNumber {
            get {
                return this.directorPhoneNumberField;
            }
            set {
                this.directorPhoneNumberField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string NationalProviderIdentifier {
            get {
                return this.nationalProviderIdentifierField;
            }
            set {
                this.nationalProviderIdentifierField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public string WebAddress {
            get {
                return this.webAddressField;
            }
            set {
                this.webAddressField = value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I used following xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Providers">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Provider">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FederalTaxIdentifier" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProviderName" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ContractualRelationshipCode" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ProviderSites">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ProviderSite">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:all>
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SiteIdentifier" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SiteName" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LicenseTypeCode" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OpenDate" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CloseDate" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DirectorPrefixName" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DirectorFirstName" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DirectorMiddleInitial" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DirectorLastName" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="DirectorPhoneNumber" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="NationalProviderIdentifier" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="WebAddress" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:all>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </schema>
```

Comment: This works thanks! I am tried to create an array for "ProviderSiteLicenseIdentifiers" like you did for "ProviderSites" and it is saying "ProvidersProvider does not contain a definition for ProviderSiteLicenseIdentifiers", what am I missing?

Comment: I just used the xsd.exe tool to generate the classes from the xsd you provided.

Comment: I figured it out, I forgot "ProviderSiteLicenseIdentifiers" was a sub element of "ProviderSites" Thanks Again!

Comment: Trying to figure out how to add an element twice, like say a director had 2 different phone numbers or there are 2 different web addresses.

Comment: You need additional columns in the table and a new element(s).  Have three phone numbers Home, Work, Cell.  You can use a list.  See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256162(v=vs.110).aspx